# VB Async/await not working with datatables

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

I'm having some problems converting this method from c# to VB, it's working flawless in C# :

```
    private async void Test()
    {
        DataSet dt;
        var client = new xxxSoapClient();

        dt = await client.ToDoAsync();
    }
```

I'm using Async/await in VS 2012, and in c# it's all ok, but when trying to do exactly the same in VB it returns an error indicating that system.void is not awaitable!!!

```
Private Async Sub Test()
    Dim dt As DataTable

    Dim Client As New xxxSoapClient
    dt = Await Client.ToDoAsync()
End Sub
```

The webservice is just returning a simple datatable, ideas someone?

Answer (score 0):

The WCF proxy generator before VS2012 would generate `*Async` methods that returned `void` and signaled their completion using events. As of VS2012, the WCF proxy generator by default will generate `*Async` methods that return `Task<T>`.

Try re-generating the proxy.

If that doesn't work, check your "advanced" options for the style of asynchronous methods to create. There are [three styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938.aspx): Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) uses `Begin*`/`End*`/`IAsyncResult`; Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP) uses `*Async`/`*Completed`/`AsyncCompletedEventArgs`; Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) uses `*Async`/`Task`.

TAP works naturally with `async`/`await`, so that's the one you want.